Can I map port(s) from a container to its host on GCE using `gcloud create-with-container`?
I am trying to spin up a dockerized web app on my GCE instance. I want to be able to access my app from the external ip provided by GCE without SSH-ing into my instance to map the ports. gcloud compute instances create-with-container instance-1 --container-image=image:latest creates a instance with a container of my image but it does not seem to allow me to map the ports. Is there some way to do this without ssh-ing into my instance?
Do I need to do all of this from the startup script ie.

download docker
run container of my image with port mapped
??

Appreciate you all taking the time to help me out here. Thanks in advance.

Verify GCE instance firewall configuration whether it allows traffic to the exposed port or not. check this similar so for more details.
